# How to a split a list in parts that have size less than 1MByte

Tags: python

I have a sorted list of dictionaries returned by a remote API call (tipically the response is less than 4 MByte.
I would like to split this list in chunks where the MAX allowed size of the resulted single chunk is 1 MByte.<sup>*</sup>

The resulted list of chunks need to preserve the initial sorting; these chunks then will be serialized (via Pickle) and put into different Blob field having 1 MByte MAX size.

What's the fastest code to achieve that with Python 2.5?

<sup>*the number of chunks should be the lowest that fits into the 1MByte constraint</sup>

Comment: [sys.getsizeof()](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) is only supported in 2.6 and higher. There might be no way to do what you want in 2.5.

Comment: Do you want the in-memory size of the dictionaries to be 1MB or are you looking at some sort of serialized representation?  Do you want to keep the chunks ordered or are you looking for an optimal packing?  I'll warn you ahead of time that "Bin Packing" is a classic example of an NP-hard problem so it might not really be worthwhile to pursue the optimal solution.

Comment: If you are Python version is < 2.6 then could look at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/546530/ in order to get size of an object in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [pympler](http://code.google.com/p/pympler/) library, the `asizeof` module provides basic size information for one or several Python objects tested with Python 2.2.3, 2.3.7, 2.4.5, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on my comment. You could use [this extension](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/546530/).
And the following script. Assume that this won't optimize the size of the chunks. It only assures that none of them are larger than MAX

```
from sizeof import asizeof

matrix=[]
new_chunk = []
size_of_current_chunk = 0
for x in your_sorted_list:
    s = asize(x)
    if size_of_current_chunk + s > MAX:
        matrix.append(new_chunk)
        size_of_current_chunk = 0
        new_chunk = []
    size_of_chunk += s
    new_chunk.append(x)

if len(new_chunk):
    matrix.append(new_chunk)
```

the element `matrix` would contain lists of objects with less than MAX bytes in each of them.

It'd be interesting to measure the performance of asize against just encoding the objects in a json string and multiplying the json string by sizeof(char).

Comment: @systempuntoout  If you need to preserve order then I think that this answer would give a possible solution. The order is preserved and the output is a list where every element is a list of chunks where the order is preserved at both levels of the matrix.

Comment: +1 for the effort but since you are testing the size n time (and I don't know the performance of asize function) it looks slow (I have to try it :) ).